# Select column from tab delimited text file in python and add it to tsv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, text, export-to-csv

I have a 3 column text file. I am trying to figure out how to select columns from the textfile and input them into an empty tsv files with specific column names. How would I go about doing this? I'm very new to python so any help for each of these stages would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myData.txt`:

```
a        b        c
1        2        3
4        5        6
```

Then You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('myData.txt',sep='\s+')
df.to_csv('someFileName.csv')
```

Comment: When I tried running this code I received this error

`
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
`

Comment: Also, how do I select, a specific column for example column 1 in myData.txt to go to a specific column (like column 2) in the new file?

Comment: @Mrl I think you're getting an error because when you ran the code the text file was open

Comment: @Mrl You can do `df['somecolumn']`